# Jquery - validate and format form field

Tags: jquery

I have a form field that the user enters the last 6 characters of a MAC address in.

I'm using JQuery to validate and format this.

The validation is based on allowed characters 0-9 A-F and -

After every second character is entered a - is added to the field.

This is the code I have:

```
$("body").on('keyup', '#macAddress', function(){
    if ($(this).val().match(/[^a-fA-F0-9-]/) != null) {
        alert('error in mac address');
        return false;
    }

    if (this.value.indexOf("-") == this.value.length - 1) $(this).val($(this).val().slice(0, -1));
    if ($(this).val().length == 2 || $(this).val().length == 5) $(this).val($(this).val() + "-");
    if ($(this).val().match(/-/g).length > 2) $(this).val($(this).val().replace($(this).val(),''));
});
```

This seems to work, but I have a couple of small issues...

1. When the first digit is entered the console log shows 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property length of null'

This relates to this line :

```
        if ($(this).val().match(/-/g).length > 2) $(this).val($(this).val().replace($(this).val(),''));
```

I'm not sure why this errors.

2. One you've entered the second character a - is added. This expected, but it stops you using backspace to delete anything.  If I enter `12` then it's changed to `12-` pressing back space tries to delete the -, which jquery re adds so you endup not being able to go back and delete.
3. I need to limit the number of characters entered, the maximum should be 8 characters eg: `xx-xx-xx` where x = `09 AF`

Anyway the above can be done my amending the code I have ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the keypress event instead and some text manipulation

```
$("body").on('keypress', '#macAddress', function(e){
    if ($(this).val().match(/[^a-fA-F0-9-]/) != null) {
        alert('error in mac address');
        return false;
    }
    if($(this).val().length > 7) {alert('length exceeded'); return false;}
    var val = $(this).val();
    plainVal = val.split('-').join('');//remove the -
    plainValArray = plainVal.split('');//creare array
    if (e.keyCode != 8) {//add - only if its not backspace 
    $.each(plainValArray,function(i,v){
      if((i+1)%2 == 0)
        plainValArray[i] = plainValArray[i]+'-';//add the - again
    });
    val = plainValArray.join('');
    };
    $(this).val(val);
});
```

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/n10omm7s/

Comment: thanks this works, the only issue is it's using Ketypress and not keyup. I prefer keyup as I'm also doing an ajax lookup of the value entered in a database.  With keyup that happens live. With keypress it doesn't..  Any ideas ?